# Filter out Html Number Via Regex

Tags: html, .net, regex, vb.net, parsing

Im trying to filter out a specific line from html source with a specific number

To problem is that its between `100` and `25000` inc of `+50`

How can i make it so that it checks between `100` and `25000` without writing 100 lines of code? `txtAmount.text contains the website html source`

This is what i got so far:

```
   Const Amount = "(<td class=""text-right"">100</td>)|(<td class=""text-right"">150</td>)|(<td class=""text-right"">200</td>)|(<td class=""text-right"">etc</td>)"

     Dim qty As New List(Of String)
            qty = txtAmount.Lines.ToList
            For i As Integer = qty.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If Not Regex.IsMatch(qty(i), Amount) Then
                    qty.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next
            txtAmount.Lines = qty.ToArray



HTML:
    <td class="text-right">100</td> <=== I need to get this number
```

Comment: What is the class name by chance? Your example it is empty with no name...

Comment: Sorry About That Here is the HTML:
`<td class="text-right">Quantity</td>
<td class="text-right">100</td>`

Comment: you just want to get the numeric value from the string?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\d` metacharacter to capture only digts (from a range of **3** digits to **5** digits in this example):

```
Dim html As String = 
    "<td class=""text-right"">Quantity</td> <td class=""text-right"">100</td>"

Dim rgx As New Regex(".+text-right.+>(?<value>\d{3,5})<.+", RegexOptions.Singleline)

If rgx.IsMatch(html) Then
    Dim value As Integer = CInt(rgx.Match(html).Groups("value").Value)
    Console.WriteLine(value) ' 100 (or whatever other digits exists in the html field.)
End If
```